# Can't find a working example of SQLite.Net-PCL in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

I can't seem to get off dead center with SQLite.Net-PCL; I have a Xamarin forms solution with a PCL proj, Droid proj, iOS proj, and Windows Universal project.  I have installed the nuget packages for SQLite.Net-PCL and SQLite.Net.Core-PCL.

So, I go over to the github project to find some awesome examples to get started and none of them work; apparently you have to pass a platform into the database connection, but I get a reference error on them all (such as SQLitePlatformWin32).

Search the web for the references and... nothing.  Search nuget for the platforms and... nothing.

What am I missing? (yes, I feel dumb)

An example they have is

```
 public class Database : SQLiteConnection
{
    public Database(string path) : base(new SQLitePlatformWin32(), path)
    {
        CreateTable<Stock>();
        CreateTable<Valuation>();
    }}
```

and I get a reference error that I can't resolve on the "new SQLitePlatformWin32" line.

Comment: look at the ToDo sample: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling, here is what you need to do.

- Install the SQLite.Net-PCL, SQLite.Net.Core-PCL and SQLite.Net.Async-PCL nugets
- Create an interface for ISQLite in your PCL:

  `public interface ISQLite
          {
              SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
          }`
- Call GetConnection via DependencyService

  `PatientDatabase = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection(); 
  PatientDatabase.CreateTable<Patient>();`
- The above will create the connection based on your platform (i.e. android, ios).  In each platform's project, you must have a GetConnection that is accessable via DependencyService such as this for Android

  `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]
  // ...
  public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
  {
      public SQLite_Android() { }
      public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
      {
          var sqliteFilename = "TodoSQLite.db3";
          string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
          var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
          // Create the connection
          var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), path);
          // Return the database connection
          return conn;
      }
  }`

My problem was I was trying to create the connection in my PCL and I couldn't find the platforms, what you need to do is create the connection in each individual project.